# Two factor Authentication error on update to symfony 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, two-factor-authentication

Here is my code sample

```
/**
 * @Route("/two/factor", name="google-authenticator")      
 */
public function twoFactorAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $secret = $this->container->get("scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator")->generateSecret();
    $user->setGoogleAuthenticatorSecret($secret);
    $url = null;
    if(!empty($user->getGoogleAuthenticatorSecret())){
        $url = $this->container->get("scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator")->getUrl($user);
    }
```

Here is error

> The "scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

It was works fine. But after updating from symfony 3.4 to 4.1 I am getting this error. please let me know how can I fix it quickly respected.

Comment: Did you upgrade from a version prior to 3.4?

Comment: It was 3.4. But I upgraded with some deprication. Actually prolem is this line.

Comment: "$this->container->get("scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator")->generateSecret();"

Comment: It is deprecated now. But I do not now how can I implement with some newer way.

Comment: I deleted my answer - I didn't notice you said you were already on 3.4. Since you are on 4.1 now you may be able to pass the service into the action directly, if it is [autowired](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-debug-autowiring-command). Run `bin/console debug:autowiring` and see if the service is available in the list that is displayed. If it is, just pass it as a type-hinted argument into the action. For example for an autowired service `Foo\BarService` do `function twoFactorAction(Request $request, Foo\BarService $barService)` and it will be usable in your action.

Comment: Thanks. I used bin/console debug:autowiring. It have not included this service. Can I do that and how if possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting. Do `bin/console debug:autowiring | grep -i scheb` just in case. What version of `schleb/two-factor-bundle` do you have installed? You should be able to see this in your composer.json.

Comment: If you are using version 4 of this library, I'd have imagined that the autowiring aliases at the [bottom of this config file](https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/4.x/Resources/config/two_factor_provider_google.xml) would be available.

Comment: I am using version 2.0 with windows respected

Comment: Here also class path I need to use as type hint

Comment: vendor\Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Provider\Google\GoogleAuthenticator

Comment: Did you have to manually configure this service? Judging from the 2.x docs you did. If so, find this configuration (`scheb_two_factor`) and add  `public: true`

Comment: YesI found. It is in scheb_two_factor.yamal. And it errors tha puplic keword not supported

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update - I suspected that it would not work. I will post an answer with your options as I see them.

Comment: Thanks respected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, Symfony 4.1 allows you to inject autowired services into your controller actions and elsewhere. However you are using an older (2.x) version of the `scheb/two-factor` library, which does not define autowired services.

Since you cannot upgrade to 4.x of this library you are somewhat restricted in your options. However it should be possible to add a [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to modify the `scheb/two-factor` library's configuration to your needs.

In short, a Compiler Pass should allow you to redefine this service as public by doing something like this:

```
$container 
    ->getDefinition('scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator')
    ->setPublic(true);
```

You'll have to refer to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to learn how to implement a compiler pass into your application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use from container anymore because access modifiers. Try to use autowiring.

You can use this interface ***GoogleAuthenticatorInterface***

It comes from the same package that you are currently using: Scheb
And have this namespace:

```
Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Provider\Google\GoogleAuthenticatorInterface;
```

Your method looks like:

```
public function index(GoogleAuthenticatorInterface $twoFactor)
{
    // ...
    $secret = $twoFactor->generateSecret();
}
```

I hope that this page can help you a little more if i am had not clear. [generating secret](https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/providers/google.md)

Comment: be sure to include the variables you were using, such as $request

Comment: Actually I am using old bundle little bit. And cannot update due to some reasons. Old bundle have no GoogleAuthenticatorInterface

Comment: This is the correct answer assuming the OP is using version 4 but I suspect they are not.

Comment: I just saw your comment Muhammad - you are not (and can not) use the latest version. That's good to know.